# Proper Use of MYSQL UPDATE Function

Tags: php, mysql

I am using MySQL query to UPDATE the information in the database.

I tried updating the information from the localhost/phpmyadmin and later on copy the code that was given in the localhost/phpmyadmin.

The problem is that the information/values are not updating in the database.

Below is the code:

```
<?php

   if(isset($_POST['updateProfile']))
     {
       $newUser = $_POST['newUsername'];
       $newPass = $_POST['newPassword'];
       $newConNum = $_POST['newContactNumber'];
       $newAdd = $_POST['newAddress'];

    include("dbconnect.php");

    //avatarPATH
    $filepath = "avatar/owner-".$_SESSION['username']."-fname-".$_SESSION['fname']."-l_name-".$_SESSION['lname']."-filename-".$_FILES["file"]["name"];

  $checkQuery = "SELECT * FROM `users`.`info` WHERE username = '".$userName."' ";
                $checkResult = $con->query($checkQuery);
                $count = mysqli_num_rows($checkResult);

                    while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($checkResult, MYSQLI_ASSOC))

                        {
                            $username = $rows['username'];
                            $userpass = $rows['password'];
                            $firstName = $rows['firstname'];
                            $lastName = $rows['lastname'];
                            $ConNum = $rows['contact_number'];
                            $usrAdd = $rows['user_address'];
                            $avaImgPth = $rows['avatar_image_path'];
                            $adminLvl = $rows['admin_level'];
                        }

                $query = "SELECT * FROM `users`.`info` WHERE username = '".$newUser."' ";
                $queryResult = $con->query($query);
                $result = mysqli_num_rows($queryResult);

                    if($result == 1)
                        {
                            echo $newUser." is already in use";
                        }

                    else
                        {
                            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "avatar/owner-".$_SESSION['username']."-fname-".$_SESSION['fname']."-l_name-".$_SESSION['lname']."-filename-".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);

                            //$updateQuery = "UPDATE `users`.`info` SET `username` = $newUser, `password` = $newPass, `contact_number` = $newConNum , `user_address` = $newAdd, `avatar_image_path` = $filepath WHERE `info`.`username` = '$username' AND `info`.`password` = '$userpass' AND `info`.`f_name` = '$firstname' AND `info`.`l_name` = '$lastname' AND `info`.`admin_level` = '$adminLvl'  AND  `info`.`contact_number` = '$ConNum' AND  AND  `info`.`user_address` = '$usrAdd' AND  `info`.`avatar_image_path` = '$avaImgPth' ";

                            $updateQuery = " UPDATE  `users`.`info` SET  `username` =  '$newUser',`password` =  '$newPass',`f_name` =  '$firstName',`l_name` =  '$lastName',`contact_number` =  '$newConNum',`user_address` =  '$newAdd',`avatar_image_path` =  '$filepath' WHERE  `info`.`username` =  'username' AND  `info`.`password` =  'userpass' AND `info`.`f_name` =  'firstName' AND  `info`.`l_name` =  'lastName' AND  `info`.`admin_level` =$adminLvl AND  `info`.`contact_number` =  '$ConNum' AND  `info`.`user_address` =  '$usrAdd' AND `info`.`avatar_image_path` =  '$avaImgPth' ";

                            echo "Profile successfully UPDATED!";
                        }

            }
    ?>
```

Thank you so much for your response.

Comment: I see following in your query `WHERE  info.username =  'username' AND  info.password =  'userpass' AND info.f_name =  'firstName' AND  info.l_name =  'lastName' AND...`, username, userpass and other string are they not a variable? is `$` missing there?

Comment: what kind of error you getting

Comment: `$executeUpdate = mysql_query( $updateQuery, $con);` you should try this and refer this link (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-update-query.htm) and you should must check db connection is working or not..

Comment: @Lepanto, I just forgot to put `$` but when I put them on. The result is still the same. The values are still not updating in the database.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to execute the query.

```
    $updateQuery =" UPDATE  `users`.`info` SET  `username` =  '$newUser',`password` =  '$newPass',`f_name` =  '$firstName',`l_name` =  '$lastName',`contact_number` =  '$newConNum',`user_address` =  '$newAdd',`avatar_image_path` =  '$filepath' WHERE  `info`.`username` =  '$username' AND  `info`.`password` =  '$userpass' AND `info`.`f_name` =  '$firstName' AND  `info`.`l_name` =  '$lastName' AND  `info`.`admin_level` =$adminLvl AND  `info`.`contact_number` =  '$ConNum' AND  `info`.`user_address` =  '$usrAdd' AND `info`.`avatar_image_path` =  '$avaImgPth' ";

    $excuteQuery = $con->query($updateQuery);
```

Comment: I added this `$excuteQuery = $con->query($updateQuery);` but still it doesn't update any information in the database.

Comment: Try to echo the query and execute it in database to check whether u r getting any sql errors.

Comment: *"You forgot to execute the query with `mysql_query()`"* --- OP is using `mysqli_*` functions.

Comment: Still nothing happens.